# background images specified in css not rendering

Tags: html, css, path, background-image

I have a PHPBB theme I am starting to construct.  In the CSS file, I have three items--a body and two divs--with background images.  The background images for the divs have ceased working in all browsers.

The site with the theme presented is here: https://www.tarazedi.com/index.php?style=7

The problem images are here: https://www.tarazedi.com/styles/wTcFresh/theme/images/site_banner.png

The CSS is located in wTcFresh/theme/.

The images are all in the same locations but there seems to be a pathing issue but is working very strangely.  I have tried using both relative and absolute URLs.  I have tried url(x);, url('x');, and url("x"); and also changing the other background elements.  In no case have the banner and logo images started working, but the body image works fine despite being in the same place and using the same syntax.  When I inspect the computed styles of the divs in Chrome the image will show as the full absolute URL correctly but the relative link links instead to tarazedi.com/images/site_banner.png which returns a 500 error because that URL is, obviously, useless.  In Edge and Firefox the inspector shows the correct link to the image but still does not render.

I have cleared browser and site-side caches with each attempt I make to fix it.

I am baffled.  What am I missing?

```css
body {
    color: #CCCCCC;
    background-color: #000000;
    background-image: url("images/bg.jpg");
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

.headerbanner {
    border: #009900 solid 4px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    background-image: url("images/site_banner.png");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.headerlogo {
    border: #003300 solid 4px;
    border-radius: 36px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("images/site_logo.png");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: left center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Why is there a `background-attachment` property set for `.headerbanner`and `.headerlogo`?

Comment: for best Practise you're URL of *anything* in your webpage from your own domain should start with a `/` and be a URL to the file, such as `/images/site_logo.png` for `www.site.com/images/site_logo.png`

Comment: its because of `background-attachment: fixed;`

Comment: @Martin this is not a path issue, if you look in Chrome inspector you can see that the images are loaded

Comment: @zgood currently on my view of the website, there is no background-attachment entity and the background image specified loads fine.... make your comment an answer `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result,adjust background-position and it is not issue with the background-image

1.Remove background:position to see the difference

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Editing it thusly fixed the problem and it now renders correctly.  Thank you very much!

```css
.headerbanner {
    border: #009900 solid 4px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    background-image: url("images/site_banner.png");
    background-position: right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    align-items: center;
}

.headerlogo {
    border: #003300 solid 4px;
    border-radius: 36px;
    background-image: url("images/site_logo.png");
    overflow: hidden;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left;
    align-items: center;
}
```